# Do I have to create a module for just one _alter function?

Tags: 7

I want to write a hook_entity_info_alter function.

Do I have to create a module just for this one function?

Comment: Yes indeed. It is very simple. Only one .info file and a .module file with your alter function. Just copy any module's info file and change it. Coding .module it seems you already know. Whenever you need new (small) custom code, keep adding in this only ..

Answer (score 2):

No...

All alter hooks are also run for themes, so you don't have to create a module.

e.g.

```
function MYTHEME_entity_info_alter(&$info) {
  // ...    
}
```

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7

"Modules may implement this hook to alter the information that defines an entity. All properties that are available in hook_entity_info() can be altered here."

Comment: I always believed that not every hook is applicable for themes. But I'm not the theme guy. Do you know any list that shows which are usable in both modules and themes, and which ones are module-only?

Comment: @Jance _All_ alter hooks can be implemented by themes. See [`drupal_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7)

Comment: @Mołot `hook_theme()`, preprocessers, and alter hooks - that's all you can implement in a theme if I remember rightly

Comment: @Clive OK, it seems [it wasn't possible some time ago](https://drupal.org/node/591794). Long time without needing it :)

Comment: @Mołot Yeah I think it was either 7.14 or 7.19 when that came in, can't quite remember